# MOSS 2007 Search Center. Altering Scope of a Search

Tags: sharepoint, search, moss

I'm creating a new Sharepoint Site Collection and as a subsite I have a Search Center.

After creating a new Content Search (File Share), I can search this using the Dropdown from the Home Page.

Searching "sharepoint" with Scope "All" : returns 4 items

Searching "sharepoint" with Scope "ISOs and Tools" : returns 2 items

Now I'm trying to configure the Search Center to use this search scope. But everytime I make a search, the results are returned as I had selected the scope "All", that means, 4 items!

How can I configure the Search to go on a specific scope?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that the default search page in the search center always searches the 'all' scope - well, it does!

If you edit the page you should be able to edit the properties of the search box. In those properties you can append to the search query 'Scope:' and the name of your scope. This scope will show up in your results page's search box, though.

Alternatively, create a new results page. In the search core results web part you can set the scope you're using for the results - it is a miscellaneous property.

You'll then need to edit your search center's home page to point the search box there to your new results page, and to do likewise on the new results page itself.

See http://andrewwburns.com/2009/02/20/search-a-single-list-and-dont-use-the-osssearchresultsaspx-page/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have reset/recrawled your content through the shared services admin.

Make sure you are restricting your Scope to the proper content source by adding a "ContentSource" rule in the SiteCollection's search settings

Make sure you have updated your scopes in shared services.